# Remove headers from Multiindex dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

How can I remove the headers of the following Multiindex dataframe?

```
                 con_df                   ...                             
  dim_2             1        2        3   ...           10      11      12
  dim_0 dim_1                             ...                             
  0     0          4.4     5.87     2.28  ...  6.35485e+06  410782  395.25
  0     1      4.56835  5.75216  2.12007  ...  6.35485e+06  410782  394.75
  0     2      4.65177  5.36424  1.81586  ...  6.35485e+06  410782  394.25
  1     0      4.83481  5.19509  1.59704  ...  6.35485e+06  410782  393.75
  1     1      5.05419  5.03307  1.42013  ...  6.35485e+06  410782  393.25
  1     2      6.0365   5.0122   1.25353  ...  6.35485e+06  410782  393.25
```

Desired result:

```
  0     0          4.4     5.87     2.28  ...  6.35485e+06  410782  395.25
  0     1      4.56835  5.75216  2.12007  ...  6.35485e+06  410782  394.75
  0     2      4.65177  5.36424  1.81586  ...  6.35485e+06  410782  394.25
  1     0      4.83481  5.19509  1.59704  ...  6.35485e+06  410782  393.75
  1     1      5.05419  5.03307  1.42013  ...  6.35485e+06  410782  393.25
  1     2      6.0365   5.0122   1.25353  ...  6.35485e+06  410782  393.25
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In pandas DataFrame are always columns, here if need remove first level use [`DataFrame.droplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.droplevel.html) with [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) for remove index and columns names:

```
df1 = df.droplevel(0, axis=1).rename_axis(index=(None, None), columns=None)
```

If want write DataFrame to file with no header:

```
df.to_csv(file, header=None)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use pandas:

-[DataFrame.droplevel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.droplevel.html)

-[MultiIndex.droplevel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.droplevel.html)

ie. `df.droplevel(0, axis=1)`